# Using SPM with multiple targets causes casting issues

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I've created an SPM package that has two targets. The second target uses the first one as a dependency.

Here is how it's description looks like:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v15)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage2",
            targets: ["MyPackage2"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "A", path: "../A"),
        .package(name: "B", path: "../B"),
        .package(name: "C", path: "../C"),
        .package(name: "D", path: "../D"),
        .package(name: "E", path: "../E"),
        .package(name: "F", path: "../F")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E",
                "F"
            ],
            resources: [
                .process("Resources")
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackageTests",
            dependencies: [
                "MyPackage"
            ]
        ),
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage2",
            dependencies: [
                "MyPackage"
            ],
            resources: [
                .process("Resources")
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

When I try to load a nib in the first target (the nib location is in the first target) it fails to cast it as itself.
This is the code I use to load the nib:

```
public final class func loadFrom(_ bundle: Bundle) -> Self {
    let nibName = String(describing: self)
    return bundle.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! Self
}
```

Please note that the loading of the nib doesn't fail. If I print the following line I get the correct result:

```
bundle.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: nil, options: nil)?.first
```

But it actually fails on `as! Self`

This is the error message:

```
Could not cast value of type 'X' (0x1109e0c98) to 'X' (0x103db62e8).
```

This issue started happening after adding the second target, but i'm not sure what am I doing wrong here? Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check in you console if you have any duplicate implementations at runtime. If so, it could be because of a bug I suppose, in SPM, where it can't resolve correctly transitive dependencies, especially ObjC ones (so I assume you had to add them again to the second target?)